# Simple Login Bot recently stopped working - Timeout Error - waitForSelector

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm required to log in to this website daily for work. I had previously found someone to build me a bot to help automate the login process and then text me to results of the login as a proof of login.

Yesterday the website went through a migration to new hosting or something similar and now I'm getting a timeout error in the script. In the code referenced below I've removed the actual username and password to keep my privacy, but if this is absolutely necessary I'm happy to share it in DM. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Here is the code referenced in the error:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  await page.goto(
    "https://prod.caseworthy.com/CaseWorthy/PortalDefault.aspx?DatabaseID=890&#/PortalDefault"
  );
  await page.waitForSelector("#UserNameField");

  await page.type("#UserNameField", "USERNAME");
  await page.type("#PasswordField", "PASSWORD");
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
  await page.click("#btnLogin");
  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
```

Here is the error text:

TimeoutError: waiting for selector `#UserNameField` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
at new WaitTask (/Users/jordansimac/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:526:34)
at DOMWorld.waitForSelectorInPage (/Users/jordansimac/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:430:26)
at Object.internalHandler.waitFor (/Users/jordansimac/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/QueryHandler.js:31:77)
at DOMWorld.waitForSelector (/Users/jordansimac/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:321:29)
at Frame.waitForSelector (/Users/jordansimac/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:925:51)
at Page.waitForSelector (/Users/jordansimac/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:2359:33)
at launchPup (/Users/jordansimac/index.js:18:14)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

I have very little experience with coding so I haven't tried anything different

Comment: Did you try https://prod.caseworthy.com/CaseWorthy/PortalDefault.aspx?DatabaseID=890&#/PortalLogin rather than PortalDefault? Or click `#signinlnk` with `await page.click("#signinlnk")` to switch to the subpage that has those user/pass inputs. Best not to use `waitForTimeout`s.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a step, on the url you wrote you need to click on `sign in` in order for the username and password fields to appear.

So adding will solve your problem.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('a#signinlnk');
await page.click('a#signinlnk');
```

Code :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let browser;
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const delay = (milliseconds) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));    
   
    await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    await page.goto('https://prod.caseworthy.com/CaseWorthy/PortalDefault.aspx?DatabaseID=890#/PortalDefault');
    // relevant part start
    await page.waitForSelector('a#signinlnk');
    await page.click('a#signinlnk');
    // relevant part end
    await page.waitForSelector('#UserNameField');
    await page.type("#UserNameField", "USERNAME");
    await page.type("#PasswordField", "PASSWORD");

    await delay(2000);
    await page.click("#btnLogin");
    await delay(5000);

})().catch(err => console.error(err)). finally(() => browser ?. close());
```

Another note is `page.waitForTimeout()` is [deprecated](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitfortimeout) which is why I added the delay function and used it instead

Update :

You could also change this in my code

```js
await delay(2000);
await page.click("#btnLogin");
await delay(5000);
```

to

```js
await page.waitForSelector("#btnLogin");
await page.click("#btnLogin");
```

and remove the `const delay = (milliseconds)...` line, as it would be faster just to wait for the `#btnLogin` selector (i.e. the Login button) instead of the 2 and 5 second delays.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this and report back if it doesn't work.